# unable to change background color of jquery pnotify plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using following plugin http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/

I am creating dialog using following jquery code..

```
window.parent.$.pnotify({ pnotify_title:"Test", pnotify_text:"hello", pnotify_type: "notice",pnotify_addclass: 'customsuccess',pnotify_shadow: false ,pnotify_history:false,pnotify_animation: {effect_in: 'fade', effect_out: 'fade'}});
```

I am trying to change the background-color of pnotify notification but whatever I do I am not able to change the background color..what could be the reason?

I have added my custom class

which has following property..

```
.customsuccess{
    background-color: blue;
    border:1px solid #bbe787;
}
```

The above code is only changing border color to blue..

Even I tried adding background-color:property to `ui-pnotify-container` class but there also change is not getting reflected and I can see my old color notice..

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Add this:

```
.customsuccess div.ui-pnotify-container {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #effedb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the styling variable - assuming you have either jqueryUI css or bootstrap css. If so, you can set "styling" to either "jqueryui" or "bootstrap".